# Tasks distributed equals between 2 agents

Tags: php, algorithm, task, distributed, agent

I have several tasks (task 1, task 2 ......) that must be done in order by 2 agents:

```
task 1: taken over by x
task 2: taken over by y
task 3: taken over by x
task 4: taken over by y
task 5: taken over by x
task 6: taken over by y
.....
```

What I want is for the tasks between the two to be shared equally.

In the current case I do not know how many tasks there are, as they can occur at different intervals.
The execution time for each agent is not relevant for this case.

What interests me is that the tasks are evenly distributed between the 2 agents, and random between them is not enough.

I save the information that the respective task was taken over by agent x in the database. Because tasks do not appear in the same loop.

Can anyone help me with an algorithm that does this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Toplogical sort, Hungarian Algorithm, Genetic Algorithm, Task schedule algorithm

Comment: Please add all clarification to the question by editing it, and also add what you've tried and not only the names of algorithms

Comment: I haven't started writing a code yet. At the moment I am analyzing which algorithm is suitable for this situation.

Comment: _I do not know how many tasks there are_ So the max trade off for evenly distributed will be just by 1.

Comment: Why do you care for any special algorithm? If the tasks should be distributed equally, there is nothing better than using modulo: all even numbered tasks are assigned to worker X, all odd numbered tasks to worker Y

Comment: The agent should register itself as owning the task when it does it.